# Tangent space of fiber bundle (or vector bundle)

Tags: smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles

The [Connection (vector_bundle)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(vector_bundle)) article of Wikipedia mentions about Ehresmann connection that a smooth map $s:M\to E$ ($E$ is any vector bundle over $M$) has a differential $ds:TM\to TE$, this means there is tangent spaces on the vector bundle $E$.

What is the condition that tangent space can be defined on fiber bundle? Article about fiber bundle and vector bundle doesn't mention that the bundle is also a smooth manifold.

IMO if both the base space and the fiber space are smooth manifolds then the fiber bundle is also a smooth manifold whose tangent space at any point has a dimmension of the sum of the dimmensions of the both spaces? In the above special case, the fiber of $E$ is $R^n$ which is a smooth manifold.

Is that right?

Comment: Yes if you also demand the transition maps be smooth.  Just take product of the charts on local trivialisations after possible refinement.

Comment: In the context of differential topology, it's commonplace to implicitly demand that all manifolds, as well as all maps between them, are smooth (this is often called *working in the smooth category*). This is the case of the article you mention.